# After installing Ubuntu on my HP desktop, it fails to boot up, any ideas whats wrong?

Tags: boot, 64-bit, hard-drive, ssd

I made a Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit USB drive, using that I installed Ubuntu onto the 1 terabyte hdd in the machine, thus erasing my windows 8 installation (I use Ubuntu on all of my computers and have always done this). After it finished installing it told me to reboot, I clicked the button to reboot and it succesfully did that.

The problem is when it is trying to boot up it does not seem to recognize my HDD as a place to boot from, it simply gives me an error stating that there are not valid boot devices. If I place a live USB in there though, it will boot fine off of that. Or if I go into the boot menu, it does not display the HDD as an option to boot from.

If it matters, I have reinstalled it twice now, and the Ubuntu installer did recognize that Ubuntu had been installed.

System Specs:

1. AMD 6 core 3.5 ghz processor
2. 24 gigabytes of ram (two 8 gb sticks and two 4 gb sticks)
3. 1 terabyte HDD
4. 128 gigabyte SSD (I was hoping to install Ubuntu on this, but mount /home on my HDD, but by now I just want a computer which boots up :/ )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I try install Ubuntu in my Utrabook HP Pavilon (500 GB HDD, 32 GB SSD).
I installed with USB drive

After try install some times, the problem to me is that I was not creating the boot loader partition.

The configuration that worked is

Before install:

1. Disable the fast boot and the Secure Boot
2. Enable the Legacy BIOS

In installation:

My partitions configuration are:

1. HDD : /home, /boot, /boot/efi (boot loader), /swap
2. SSD : /

After  to install enable the fast boot.
With this configuration, my Ubuntu installed with successful!
Sorry my bad English :)
I hope  I helped you!